# Open different contact form based on which Wordpress page I am

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

So basically I have several pages with Woocommerce products listed in them (same products in Page 1 and Page 2) . What I have to do is basically open up different form based on which page the product was clicked on.

Example:

I open 1st page width products and click on product -> Form nr 1 Opens
I open 2nd page with products and click on product -> Form nr 2 Opens

Any ideas how to approach this problem? Don't know which direction to even look.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a content filter to detect the page and amend the content of it.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_content_filter' );

function gwp_ec_content_filter ($content)
{
    global $post;

    if ($post->ID == $page1_page_id)
    {
        // Change $content

    } else if ($post->ID == $page2_page_id)
    {
        // Change $content
    }
}
```

Or if you doing this inside a theme page template, then

```
global $post;

    if ($post->ID == $page1_page_id)
    {
        // open form 1

    } else if ($post->ID == $page2_page_id)
    {
        // open form 2
    }
```